# How to connect a django project to a simple storage service

Tags: python, django, cloud

I want to connect my django project to a simple storage service (for example Amazon S3). How should I configure my settings.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
This is my settings for django-storages and S3

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = ''
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/your-folder/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage"
```